# Why no std::as_const overload for pointer types

Tags: c++, c++17, std

I just came across [`std::as_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const) and I was surprised by the output of the last line in the following snippet:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>

struct S {
    void foo() { std::puts("foo: non const"); }
    void foo() const { std::puts("foo: const"); }
};

int main() {
    S s;
    s.foo(); // foo: non const
    std::as_const(s).foo(); // foo: const

    auto* s_ptr = &s;
    s_ptr->foo(); // foo: non const
    std::as_const(s_ptr)->foo(); // foo: non const (?)
}
```

Looking at the documentation, I understand why the non-`const` overload of `foo` gets called:
`std::as_const(s_ptr)` returns a `S* const&`, i.e. a reference to a constant
pointer to non constant `S`, instead of a `S const*`, i.e. a pointer to a constant `S`, as I would
have expected.

So, my question is why doesn't the standard provide a `std::as_const` overload for pointer types too? E.g. something like:

```cpp
template <class T>
constexpr std::add_const_t<T>* as_const(T* t) noexcept {
    return t;
}
```

---

**Edit:** one of the motivations for `std::as_const` in paper [P0007R1](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0007r1.html#4.0) is the selection of a function oveload without having to resort to a `const_cast`. P0007R1 provides this example:

```
int processEmployees( std::vector< Employee > &employeeList );
bool processEmployees( const std::vector< Employee > &employeeList );
```

> A larger project often needs to call functions, like `processEmployees`, and
> selecting among specific `const` or non-`const` overloads. [...]

That's why I was somehow surprised it doesn't help in overload resolution when
applied to a pointer in code like the one I posted, nor in:

```
std::as_const(this)->foo();
```

nor in selecting the latter of the following overloads:

```
int processEmployees( std::vector< Employee > *employeeList );
bool processEmployees( const std::vector< Employee > *employeeList );
```

Comment: The proposed difference in behavior would be a disaster for template functions.

Comment: *"as I would have expected"* - that's the problem. Attached to *anything else*, the "thing" is const. That pointers have the luxury of attaching const-ness in two places (the pointer itself and the entity it points to) doesn't change that idiom of `std::as_const`, and it *shouldn't*.

Comment: What do you propose `int*** p; std::as_const(p)` should do? Here, there are four different spots where `const` could be introduced.

Comment: I'm _asking_ a question. I'm not _proposing_ anything.

Comment: Well, you had expected that `as_const<int*>` return `int const*` rather than `int* const`. What would you have expected from `as_const<int***>`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I expected `std::as_const` would allow me to select `void f(T const*)` over `void f(T*)` the same way it allows me to select `void f(T const&)` over `void f(T&)`. So, I'd have expected `std::as_const<int***>` to return me a `int** const*`.

Comment: `std::as_const(*this).foo();`

Comment: What about `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`? What about iterators (all of them, including those not written yet)? Do you expect something special to happen there?

Comment: What's wrong with `std::as_const(*s_ptr).foo();`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of `std::as_const` is to be able to reference a non-`const` lvalue as a `const` lvalue so that it isn't modifiable in the context in which it is used. In other words `std::as_const(x)` should be a shorthand for writing

```
const auto& y = x;
```

and then using `y`.

It already does that well, so there is no need for special behavior for pointers.

And here is a simple example where the suggested additional overload would have serious negative effects:

```
std::vector<int> vec = /*...*/;
for(auto it = std::begin(vec); it != std::end(vec); it++)
    func(std::as_const(it));
```

The intention here is to make sure that the function `func` cannot modify `it` since the responsibility of iterating over the vector lies with the `for` loop. If `func` simply takes an iterator by-value or `const` reference, then `std::as_const` is not strictly required, but it makes sense anyway as a safety measure or because there are multiple overloads of `func`, some of which do modify their argument.

`auto` here is some iterator type. It *could* be a pointer. Or it could be a class type. With your suggested overload of `as_const` this would break depending on how the `std::vector` iterator is implemented.

`std::as_const(it)` is supposed to say that `it` shall not be modified through this use. It shouldn't say anything about whether the object `it` references is modifiable. That is not its purpose. Of course it could make sense to add a function that makes the *referenced* object non-modifiable. But that should have a different name and you would probably want to implement it for arbitrary iterators, not pointers specifically. Basically, an iterator-to-`const`-iterator adaptor.